# App crashing on Android Emulator but working on Genymotion emulator

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

I have an app which is working fine on Genymotion emulators. When I try to use it on an Android emulator, it keeps on crashing. The configuration of both emulators is same in terms of memory, heap size and API level.

How to make the app work on Android emulators?

Comment: please post crash logs.

Comment: I guess it is because of GooglePlay services you are using which is not in your android emulator but gapps is there in the genymotion.